# Why is this make not working?

Tags: ubuntu, make, cmake, xfce4-terminal, cern-root

I am attempting to install CERN's root software and I am on the final step of installation. The steps im taking are these.

1) Get the sources of the latest ROOT (see above)

2) Type the build commands:

```
   mkdir <builddir>
   cd <builddir>
   cmake ../root
   cmake --build . [ -- -j<N> ] [ or simply "make -j<N>" on Unix systems ]
```

I follow this by inputing

```
sudo make -j3
```

And 79% of the way through my download, after closing the laptop for a short period, I get this error.

```
[ 79%] Linking CXX executable ../bin/rootcling
ln: failed to create hard link 'rootcint' => 'rootcling': Operation not permitted
main/CMakeFiles/rootcling.dir/build.make:87: recipe for target 'bin/rootcling' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/rootcling] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'bin/rootcling'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:25797: recipe for target 'main/CMakeFiles/rootcling.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [main/CMakeFiles/rootcling.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:151: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Im using the most up to date version of cmake and I downloaded all the prerequisites for ROOT. This is all being installed in a usb flashdrive with read,write, and executable permissions.

Comment: *"being installed in a usb flashdrive"* - what filesystem does the drive use? perhaps it does not support hard links

Comment: It says it uses vfat, does vfat not support hard links and if not can I change the file system without wiping the contents?

Comment: no, vfat does not support hard links and you cannot just change the filesystem while keeping the data. That's not the only limitation of the msdos/vfat fs. You better install it on a Unix-compatible filesystem like ext4.

Comment: @Mosvy that is the answer (please migrate comment to answer).

Comment: Thank you!, ill just have to look into how to install it with ext.4 then.